# Definition of smallest cyclic code in $\mathbb F_2$

Tags: number-theory, coding-theory

I am confused about what the the following statement means:

"Being $C$ the smallest cyclic code on $\mathbb F_2$ containing the word $w = 110110$".

Maybe it's a stupid question, but does the smallest refer to the dimension or the length?

The exercise also asks me to list $C$'s words and the solution is something like this:

$0$, $w$, $w'$ (first shifting of $w$), and $w+w'$. I would have done all the shifts of $w$, so did he take just one ($w'$) because of the definition of "smallest"?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Smallest can only refer to the dimension. All the words of a cyclic code share the same length (this applies to all linear codes actually), so the length is six, and your task is to find the linear code (so closed under sums) containing $w$ and all its cyclic shifts (in theory there are six of them, but not all need to be distinct or linearly independent).

Comment: Good! If you now understand the solution, feel free to explain it as an answer. That way you get more feedback, and the question gets out of the unanswered pile :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being C the smallest cyclic code refer to the dimension(number of word in the code).
So the list of C's words, is given by the null vector, w, w' (first cyclic shifts of w), w+w'. At this point we don't need other w's shift given that our set(0, w, w', w+w') is enough for our goal and it's easy to check that this set is a cyclic code.

Comment: good. you can accept your own answer.